# Incoming WebHook and dynamic user-name/channel

Tags: curl, slack, slack-api

I was using Legacy token and I was able to send any channel with any user name. But when I switch to use incoming webhook feature then its only works for only one channel that we selected during creating webhook. Here is what I am using,

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"text":"Hello, World!","channel":"#my-channel" }' https://hooks.slack.com/services/XX/XX/XX
```

Here message is always sent to default channel instead of channel that I am specifying in CURL.

What is easiest way to send slack message to any channel with any user-name (other than legacy token)? I am also not seeing any client credentials(server to server) flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send message to any channel with a custom username your best option is to use the Slack API with [chat.postMessage](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage).

Note that you will need an Oauth token with the necessary scopes (e.g. `chat:write:user`), which requires you to create a Slack app and auth it to your workspace.

If you are working within your own workspace, you can get your auth done directly within the Slack App management page (See [internal integrations](https://api.slack.com/internal-integrations)). Otherwise you will need to implement an Oauth flow for your app (see [Add To Slack](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth)).

Here is an example curl:

```
curl https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage -X POST --data "token=TOKEN&channel=test&username=Luke Skywalker&icon_emoji=:dog:&text=The force is with me"
```

Comment: Is client credentials flow supported? How can I get a token to send chat.postMessage from my server without involving a user?

Comment: Assuming you have created your Slack app in the same workspace you want to use: you can create your token on the Slack Web App page under "Oauth". And you only need to do that once.

Comment: In the manage apps I don't see any option to generate the token?

Comment: Be careful not to confuse "Manage apps" and "Manage Your apps". Here is a direct link to "Your apps": https://api.slack.com/apps